# Python: Run command for another software in terminal

Tags: python, linux, unix, terminal

I am using a software that my lab has developed, lets call it `cool_software`. When I type `cool_software` on terminal, basically I get a new prompt `cool_software >` and I can imput commands to this software from the terminal.

Now I would like to automate this in Python, however I am not sure how to pass the `cool_software` commands onto it. Here's my MWE:

```py
import os
os.system(`cool_software`)           
os.system(`command_for_cool_software`)
```

The problem with the code above is that `command_for_cool_software` is executed in the usual unix shell, it is not executed by the `cool_software`.

Comment: Use [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Or use `subprocess.Popen()` and then write `command_for_cool_software` to the `stdin` pipe.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you!! I am very interested in the `subprocess` solution. How would it look like?

Comment: @Barmar perhaps `subprocess.Popen(["cool_software"], stdin="command_for_cool_software")`

Comment: If that's the only input, that would work.

Comment: But if you need to send a bunch of inputs, possibly conditional on the prompts, pexpect is more appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar okay thank you. Is there any chance you could help me out with that? I'm quite new to python in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Barmar suggestion from the comments, using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is pretty neat. From the documentation:

> The spawn class is the more powerful interface to the Pexpect system. You can use this to spawn a child program then interact with it by sending input and expecting responses (waiting for patterns in the child’s output).

This is a working example using the `python` prompt as an example:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("python") # mimcs running $python
child.sendline('print("hello")') # >>> print("hello")
child.expect("hello") # expects hello
print(child.after) # prints "hello"
child.close()
```

In your case, it will be like this:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("cool_software")
child.sendline(command_for_cool_software)
child.expect(expected_output) # catch the expected output
print(child.after)
child.close()
```

### NOTE

`child.expect()` matches only what you expect. If you don't expect anything and want to get all the output since you started `spawn`, then you can use `child.expect('.+')` which would match everything.

This is what I got:

```
b'Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) \r\n[GCC 9.4.0] on linux\r\nType "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.\r\n>>> print("hello")\r\nhello\r\n>>> '
```

Comment: Thank you!! Would `expected output` be the name of the output?

Comment: From the documentation: **The spawn class is the more powerful interface to the Pexpect system. You can use this to spawn a child program then interact with it by sending input and expecting responses (waiting for patterns in the child’s output).**

Comment: @Euler_Salter, sorry I misread your question. I thought you were asking about what `expect()` does. Regarding to your question, I edited my answer. Hope this helps